# Classpath trouble using JUnit with both Eclipse and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, junit

In a JUnit test I'm using this code to load in a test-specific config file:

```
InputStream configFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.xml");
```

When I run the test through eclipse, it requires the xml file to be in the same directory as the test file.

When I build the project with maven, it requires the xml to be in `src/test/resources`, so that it gets copied into `target/test-classes`.

How can I make them both work with just one file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Place the config.xml file in src/test/resources, and add src/test/resources as a source folder in Eclipse.

The other issue is how `getResourceAsStream("config.xml")` works with packages.  If the class that's calling this is in the `com.mycompany.whatever` package, then `getResourceAsStream` is also expecting config.xml to be in the same path.  However, this is the same path in the *classpath* not the file system.  You can either place file in the same directory structure under src/test/resources - src/test/resources/com/mycompany/whatever/config.xml - or you can add a leading "/" to the path - this makes `getResourceAsStream` load the file from the base of the classpath - so if you change it to `getResourceAsStream("/config.xml")` you can just put the file in src/test/resources/config.xml

Comment: That's it! The / was the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `src/test/resources/` directory as a source folder in your Eclipse project.  That way, it should be on the classpath when Eclipse tries to run your unit test.

Comment: Sadly, this single saving comment took me a full day to find. Solved my problem of tests that get resource bundles running fine in Maven but failing when run in Eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled on it and found it odd that none of the above answers mention the Maven Eclipse Plugin. Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and it will add *src/main/resources* and *src/test/resources* and such to the "Java Build Path" in Eclipse for you.

It has a bunch of stuff you can configure from there too (if you need to deviate from the conventions, if you don't then it's already ready to go):

- [Maven Eclipse Plugin - eclipse:eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html)
- [Maven Eclipse Plugin - sourceIncludes/sourceExcludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/specifying-source-path-inclusions-and-exclusions.html)

In general, if you're using Maven, don't manually change stuff in Eclipse. Never commit your .classpath/.project and instead just use the Maven Eclipse Plugin to generate those files (and or update them). That way you have ONE configuration source for your project, MAVEN, and not manual settings that you end up having to tell others to use and remember yourself and so on. If it's a Maven project: check it out of source control, run "mvn eclipse:eclipse" and it should work in Eclipse, if it doesn't your POM needs work.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need it at test time, you can load it via the file system, the context here should be the same for both cases:

```
new FileInputStream(new File("target/test-classes/your.file"));
```

not pretty, but it works